# Solidity Library call gives Member not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup

Tags: solidity, library

Using Solidity `0.4.17`, I have defined a simple `library` at `./StringUtils.sol`

```
library StringUtils {
    function isEmptyString(string s) external pure returns (bool) {
        return (keccak256(s) == keccak256(''));
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to use it in a `contract` at `./PastryChef.sol`

```
import './StringUtils.sol';


contract PastryChef {
    using StringUtils for StringUtils;

    string name;

    function PastryChef(string _name) public {
        require(!StringUtils.isEmptyString(_name)); // name must not be empty
        name = _name;
    }

}
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Member "isEmptyString" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library StringUtils)
        require(!StringUtils.isEmptyString(_name)); // name must not be empty
                 ^-----------------------^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked this out.  The Library function can not be `external` but must be either `internal` or `public`.

So changing `external` to `internal` fixes it.